# I want to remove filter by color attribute and its value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, foreach, nested-loops

My ecommerce have many Attributes for filter product . Every Attributes showing with foreach loop . Now I Want to remove filter by color and it's value. How I can Do it.

[This Image red circle I want To skip it from loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY8P7.png)
the site link is https://unikart.com.bd/category/skin

My code is Given below.

```
@foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
    <div class="bg-white shadow-sm rounded mb-3">
        <div class="fs-15 fw-600 p-3 border-bottom">
            {{ translate('Filter by') }} {{ $attribute->getTranslation('name') }}
        </div>
        <div class="p-3">
            <div class="aiz-checkbox-list others-attributes" id="attribute_list-{{$attribute->id}}" >
            
                @foreach ($attribute->attribute_values as $attribute_value)
                    <label class="aiz-checkbox">
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="selected_attribute_values[]"
                            value="{{ $attribute_value->value }}" @if (in_array($attribute_value->value, $selected_attribute_values)) checked @endif
                            onchange="filter()"
                        >
                        <span class="aiz-square-check"></span>
                        <span>{{ $attribute_value->value }}</span>
                    </label>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="ViewMore" id="ViewMore-{{$attribute->id}}" onclick="ViewMore({{$attribute->id}})">View More</div>
    <div class="ViewLess" id="ViewLess-{{$attribute->id}}" onclick="ViewLess({{$attribute->id}})">View Less</div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you please show the relation in model ? 
We can add the where condition there which gonna work fo you

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter to attributes on backend

example:
$attributes = Attribute::where('type', '!=', 'color')->get();

If you add backend code screenshot, the answer would be clearer.